# CMSIS and HAL at one project integrating CMSIS and HAL

Tags: stm32, keil, stm32f4, hal, cmsis

I am wondering, is it possible to add CMSIS  and HAL libraries at the same project in KEIL...
based on my knowledge I added CMSIS libraries in different folder but in compiling I got these errors...

Do you guys have faced with this problem?
Can you help me?
note: the main project was written in CMSIS and I don't want to rewrite it in Hal.
There are 2 files:1-stm32f4xx_hal.h,2-stm32f4xx.h
The first one is defined and used in HAL and the second one is for CMSIS, how can I use both of them in one project?
THIS IS THE ERROR:" #error "Please select first the target STM32F4xx device used in your application (in stm32f4xx.h file)"  "
and in below is the screenshot.

[image]
[image]
THANKS.

Comment: You need to have project-wide definition of your target processor.

Answer (score 0):

The STM32 HAL always depends on CMSIS.  You cannot use the HAL library without CMSIS.

The error message you have received clearly explains what you have done wrong and what you need to do to fix it.  I cannot explain it any more clearly than that.

```
#error Please select first the target STM32F4xx device used in your application
```

You might also appreciate to read the comment immediately before the line you have highlighted:

```
/*  Tip: To avoid modifying this file each time you need to switch between these
    devices, you can define the device in your toolchain compiler preprocessor.
*/
```

Comment: CMSIS is more than the part provided by STM with peripheral definitions

Comment: Yes I know.  It has many components.  STM32 HAL doesn't depends on the Neural Networking or DSP part, obviously, only some of the core functions.  The point I was making is that the OP was wrong to think that you could only have either HAL or CMSIS,

Comment: I avoid CMIS in bare metal understanding. Less confusion